# @Transactional within PanacheEntity?

Tags: quarkus

Is this allowed in quarkus?

```
@Entity
public class User extends PanacheEntity  {

    // is @Transactional annotation allowed within an Entity
    @Transactional 
    public static final updateName(String name){
       ...
    }

}
```

Does quarkus allow the annotation `@Transactional` to be set within a **static method** (which is normally not bound to a context (CDI-Bean))..depending  on `PanacheEntity`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not allowed.

You will get `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Transaction is not active, consider adding @Transactional to your method to automatically activate one.`

You have to add the annotation `@Transactional` to the wrapping method of your resource.

The built-in method `persist()` does not have the annotation set, so even the quarkus default method wont work without a wrapped `@Transactional`.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. **The question was about:** if quarkus allows the annotation `@Transactional` to be set within a **static method** (which is normally not bound to a context (CDI-Bean)).

Comment: Not quite sure what your usecase is, but you need the annotation at the top level, that means at the resources (JAX-RS). Your question is a bit misleading...your code is clearly showing a PanacheEntity, but it should independent of the PanacheEntity? Would you mind to provide an example that should work in your case? :)

Comment: It s a entity Bean with a static method using  @transactinal

Comment: Than my answer should be correct. You have to provide the `@Transactional` out side the entity itself. The method of the entity can be static.